# Не удаляется и не добавляется класс при изменении разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть основное меню и выпадающее меню, я сделала чтобы оно появлялось при наведении и при клике(при добавлении класса). Но есть проблема в планшетной версии, меню еще не скрывается и надо чтобы при клике появлялось выпадающее меню, а при обратном клике скрывалось, ему мешает hover и поэтому при обратном клике на него же оно не скрывается, а скрывается только тогда когда я нажму на другую ссылку или просто в другом месте экрана.

Я нашла другое решение - навесила новый класс и ему сделала hover, при определенном разрешении экрана этот класс удаляется и не мешает клику, но мой код не работает.

```js
if($(window).width() > 992) {
        $('.nav-menu__item').addClass('.nav-menu__item--hover');
    } else {
        $('.nav-menu__item').removeClass('.nav-menu__item--hover');
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 992) {
            $('.nav-menu__item').addClass('.nav-menu__item--hover');
        } else {
            $('.nav-menu__item').removeClass('.nav-menu__item--hover');
         }
    });

    $('.nav-menu__item').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('show-dropdown');
    });
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-top: 22px;
  width: 242px;
  left: 0;
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform:perspective(400) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
  transform-origin:50% 0;
  transition:350ms;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;

  &__item {
    margin: 0 15px;
    position: relative;

    &--hover:hover, &.show-dropdown {
      .dropdown-menu {
        max-height:1000px;
        transform:perspective(400) rotate3d(0,0,0,0);
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
.nav-menu__item
    a.nav-menu__link(href="#") Магазины
    .dropdown-menu
      .dropdown-menu__list
        .dropdown-menu__item
          +icon('arrow-right', 'dropdown-menu__icon')
          a.dropdown-menu__link(href="#") Киев «MatroLuxe», ул. Беломорская, 2
        .dropdown-menu__item
          +icon('arrow-right', 'dropdown-menu__icon')
          a.dropdown-menu__link(href="#") Днепр «MatroLuxe» пр. Александра Поля, 97а
        .dropdown-menu__item
          +icon('arrow-right', 'dropdown-menu__icon')
          a.dropdown-menu__link(href="#") Днепр «MatroLuxe» пр. Александра Поля, 96
        .dropdown-menu__item
          +icon('arrow-right', 'dropdown-menu__icon')
          a.dropdown-menu__link(href="#") Днепр «MatroLuxe» пр. Александра Поля, 96
```

Comment: может медиа запросы лучше использовать

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, помогло, прописала hover и добавление класса при клике в медиа запросаx:

```css
.nav-menu {
  display: flex;

  &__item {
    margin: 0 15px;
    position: relative;

    @media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
      &--hover:hover {
        .dropdown-menu {
          max-height:1000px;
          transform:perspective(400) rotate3d(0,0,0,0);
        }
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
      &.show-dropdown {
        .dropdown-menu {
          max-height:1000px;
          transform:perspective(400) rotate3d(0,0,0,0);
        }
      }
    }
     
  }
}
```